Is there some way to directly run the q8 function without having to manually run the calculate and verifyshare functions?
`    // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0; 

contract ImageShareCommitments {
    uint256 public g;
    uint256 public h;
    uint256 public p;
    uint256 public check;
    constructor() {
        // Generating random numbers
        uint256 randomSeed = uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.timestamp, block.basefee, msg.sender))); 
        g = (randomSeed % 49) + 1; // Random between 1 and 50
        h = (randomSeed % 49) + 3; // Random between 1 and 50

        // Assigning a prime number
        p = 17;
    }

    struct Commitment { 
        uint256 commitmentValue;
        // uint256 timestamp; 
    }

    mapping(uint256 => Commitment) public commitments; 

    function calculate(uint256 index, uint256 shares, uint256 xValue) public{ 
        uint256 g_fx = calculateModularExp(g, shares, p);
        uint256 h_x = calculateModularExp(h, xValue, p);

        check = (g_fx * h_x) % p;
        commitments[index] = Commitment(check);
        //return commitments[index].commitmentValue;
    } 

    function verifyShare(uint256 share, uint256 xValue, uint256 index) public view returns (bool) {
        // Commitment memory storedCommitment = commitments[index];

        uint256 g_fx = calculateModularExp(g, share, p);
        uint256 h_x = calculateModularExp(h, xValue, p);

        uint256 calculatedValue = (g_fx * h_x) % p;
        if(calculatedValue != commitments[index].commitmentValue){
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function calculateModularExp(uint256 base, uint256 exp, uint256 modulus) public pure returns (uint256) {
        base = base % modulus; // Ensure base is within the modulus range
        uint256 result = 1;
        while (exp > 0) {
            if (exp % 2 == 1) { // Current exponent bit is 1
                result = (result * base) % modulus;
            }
            exp = exp >> 1;     // Shift exponent to the right
            base = (base * base) % modulus;
        }
        return result;
    }

    function findPrime() public pure returns (uint256) {
        uint256 num = 2;
        while (true) {
            if (isPrime(num)) {
                return num; 
            }
            num++;
        }
        return 0; // Default return if no prime is found (indicates an issue)
    }

    function isPrime(uint256 num) public pure returns (bool) {
        if (num <= 1) {
            return false;
        }
        for (uint256 i = 2; i * i <= num; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    function q8() public view returns (bool) {
        calculate

(1, 557509, 8);
        return verifyShare(557509, 8, 1);
    }
}    `

In the remix IDE, I have the problem that I have to give all the inputs for the calculate and verifyshare functions manually, in the deploy window which takes quite a lot of time. I want to be able to run the q8 function directly, as all the required parameters for calculate and verifyshare are already mentioned in the function. So, basically I want to be able to press the q8 function button and directly get the true/false answer I need.
